# What does "get to" mean?

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

I know there are a lot of meanings to the verb "get", so I am unable to understand which one is used in the following sentence:

> They had a baby which was different, so it got to live.

I know that "get to" can be:

- allowed to,
- have a chance to, or
- become (eventually)

But neither works for me. Maybe the first one would make sense. Or should it be "have got to"? That would make sense, but I thought I had to use it with "have".

Comment: Is this phrase from South Park? :)) About the retarded fish-frog?

Comment: Seems like something one would go to a dictionary for.

Answer (score 2):

Your first idea already matches perfectly.

> They had a baby which was different, so it got to live.

This could be written as:

> They had a baby which was different, so it had a chance to live.

---

"have got" indicates possession of some sort, so in this case it doesn't apply. The baby can not "possess" the verb "living". You can only possess *something*. In this case, you could of course use "chance to" as the noun here:

> They had a baby which was different, so it had gotten a chance to live.

However, this sounds way too complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I meant "have got" used as "must". I think in US English, "have got to live" could be said as "got to live", couldnt it?

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, that doesn't apply either. Do you mean, the baby *must* have gotten the chance to live *because* it was different? I guess it depends on the context here, but I'd say this is a very specialized interpretation.

Comment: @Pietro No, it couldn’t.  “I got to live” is substandard.

Comment: @tchrist In writing, perhaps, it would be substandard, with _I'**ve** got to live_ as standard. However, in actual spoken English, the intervoxcalic [vɡ] cluster is almost never pronounced; the [v] drops and we get _I got_; in fact, we get _I gotta_; this idiom is always followed by an infinitive, since it's a modal paraphrase and works like _must_.